# Ninject 2 for CF3.5 TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, ninject, coldfusion

In middle of application when calling following line:

```
var component = _Kernel.Get<IComponent>();
```

I'm getting TargetInvocationException. IComponent is a Form.

> at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[]
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   Ninject.Injection.ReflectionInjectorFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object[]
>   args)    at
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext
>   context)    at
>   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
>   at
>   Ninject.KernelBase.b__7(IContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__d`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext
>   parent)    at
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext
>   context, ITarget target)    at
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Create>b__1(ITarget target)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__d`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext
>   context)    at
>   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
>
>   at
>   Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__d`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__b0`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot
>   root, IParameter[] parameters)

Comment: i've moved to compact container and i'm happy now.

Answer (score 1):

When asking for help, you need to give some context. There is a lot going on and if you don't give any context, it is nearly impossible to help. Give a reproduction scenario, or a small piece of the object being created. Was it an internal class, protected .ctor, etc. The more information you give the easier it is to help.